# cakephp relations model

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a site developed in CakePHP 2.0.
I have a database with many tables and I want to relation two tables. I have done this many times, but with two tables I can't do this and I don't know why.
This is my two tables:

ingredient_aliases:

```
id             INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT 
ingredient_id  INT(10)          
user_id        INT(10)          
alias          VARCHAR(100) latin1_swedish_ci
```

acitivity_ingredients

```
id             INT(10) UNSIGNED     
activity_id    INT(11)      
ingredient_id  INT(10)          
created        DATETIME
```

ingredient_id is my foreign key and this is my model, I want to to make the `ingredient_id` my foreign key.

```
class ActivityIngredients extends AppModel{
        public $name = 'ActivityIngredients'; 
        public $useTable = 'activity_ingredients';

        public $belongsTo = array(
            'IngredientAlias' => array(
                'className'     => 'IngredientAlias',
                'conditions'    => '',
                'order'         => '',
                'foreignKey'    => 'ingredient_id'
            )
        );


    }

class IngredientAlias extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'IngredientAlias';
    public $useTable = 'ingredient_aliases';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Ingredient' => array(
            'className'    => 'Ingredient',
            'foreignKey'   => 'ingredient_id'
        ),
         'User' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array (
        'ActivityIngredients' => array (
            'className'     => 'ActivityIngredients',
            'dependent' => true,
            'foreignKey'   => false,
            'associatedKey'   => 'ingredient_id'            
        )
    );
```

When I make the var_dump of my variables in `IngredientAlias` there is nothing, is empty like it doesn't take the foreign key.. why?
The problem is in the relations? 
I have try to write

```
'foreignKey'   => 'ingredient_id'
```

But nothing.. same

The query is a simple query with 3 of recursive, a select all i think is not there the problem but in the relation with the table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how hasMany/belongsTo relationships work.

Your current code describes a relationship where:

- `ActiveIngredient` *belongs to* `IngredientAlias`
- `IngredientAlias` *has many* `ActiveIngredient`

This is a **one-to-many** relationship from `IngredientAlias` to `ActiveIngredient`.

But your database schema describes the following table relationships:

- `ActiveIngredient` *belongs to* `Ingredient`
- `Ingredient` *has many* `ActiveIngredient`
- `IngredientAlias` *belongs to* `Ingredient`
- `Ingredient` *has many* `IngredientAlias`

In other words, a **one-to-many** relationship from `Ingredient` to `ActiveIngredient`, and another **one-to-many** relationship from `Ingredient` to `IngredientAlias`.

So your model relationships should be exactly what the database schema describes. (Also, your foreign keys should reference a candidate key. MySQL allows you to create foreign key constraints that aren't referencing a candidate key, but I don't think most other databases allow this; thus CakePHP probably also doesn't allow it.)

Lastly, `recursive` levels in CakePHP range from `-1` to `2` (inclusive). There is no `recursive` level of `3`. If you simply set `recursive` to `2`, then a `findAll` on `ActiveIngredient` will return its parent `Ingredient` and that parent `Ingredient`'s child `IngredientAliases`.

---

**Edit:**
`recursive` uses multiple queries under the hood. However, most of the time, it's going to fetch a lot of unnecessary data from models you don't need. The best thing to do is to either use [`unbindModel()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#dynamic-associations) to remove the associations that aren't need, or, where possible, set `recursive` to `-1` and [use `joins`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) to fetch associated data.

Another variation of the first option is to use [the Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). This lets you define the exact relations and fields that you want returned. This is usually the easiest way to optimize finds that require recursive queries.

Comment: I understand and now I have tried to make this relations but the problem is now in the findAll, this is my code:
$user = $this->User->findAll (array('id'=>$id));
  $this->set('user', $user);

Comment: And is possible to make findAll with a a specific id? Because in my view I pass an id for te Ingredient

Comment: @Alessandro: If you want to `findAll` by a particular field (e.g. `id`), you can use `findAllByFieldname` (i.e. `findAllById($id)`). However, `findAll` is designed for returning multiple results, so it doesn't make sense to do `findAllById` but rather `findById`, since IDs are unique. [See the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) for how to use these methods.

Comment: I have done the relations like the database but when I make the findAllById I can't reach IngredientAlias.. Because the query in on User table related with many others.. is a very big query to retrieve data like Profile Activity (ActivityIngredients, Ingredient,IngredientAlias)
this is the code:
$this->User->recursive = 2;
  
  $user = $this->User->findAllById ($id);
  
  $this->set('user', $user);

Comment: I don't know if is better to make more query or only one with findAllById

Comment: @Alessandro: The best way to go is probably to use the Containable behavior as explained in my edit. Cake will still do multiple queries behind the scenes if you ask it to fetch data from associated models, but you can trim out everything you don't need.

Comment: But if i use the findallbyid like your edit  doesn't work for this reason i think that the best way is to make multiple queries